# Can't display my own id in apex:inputField in browser

Tags: visualforce

I am very new to apex and just start to study how to add validation on the field. I am not able to do this from set up. In more detail I want to assign an id to apex:inputfield. I read a lot of information in the internet such as using partial id like http://www.kineticgrowth.com/javascript-visualforce-jquery-partial-id-selectors/

However know matter what I add in apex page, it doesn't show up inside the string. Here is my code:

```
<apex:pageBlock id="pageBlock" ...>
...
<apex:dataTable ...  id="transTableBrandPurchase" ">
...
<apex:inputField id="eric_test" value="{!varBla}" required="true" />
```

when I check the browser in html it gets

```
<input id="j_id0:j_id6:pageBlock:transTableManufacturerPurchase:0:j_id273" maxlength="255" name="j_id0:j_id6:pageBlock:transTableManufacturerPurchase:0:j_id273" size="20" type="text">
```

Based on Salesforce reference I should `get id="j_xxx:j_yyy ...:pageBlock:transTableManufacturerPurchase:eric_test"`

People may say that I can just use "pageBlock:transTableManufacturerPurchase", I cann't because in this page we display then rows and the other rows look like similar:

```
 <input id="j_id0:j_id6:pageBlock:transTableManufacturerPurchase:0:j_id275" name="j_id0:j_id6:pageBlock:transTableManufacturerPurchase:0:j_id275" >
```

Right now I am working on validation in visualforce page with Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

My approach to assigning ID to elements in VF page is, give ID to all apex elements. Then use chrome inspect element option to find exact ID.

If you are using salesforce any repeat tags , , etc, salesforce will add additional numbering on your ID, to make sure that all elements have unique ID.